# Using finders to query a referenced model in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called `Person` that `has_one Address`. `Person` has fields like `first_name` and `last_name`; `Address` has `postal_code`, `state`, and so on.

I know how to use finders to find all people with a certain name; that's `Person.find_by_last_name("Smith")`. But how do I find all people where:

- their first_name is "Bob"; and
- their last_name is "Smith"; and
- who have addresses with a city of 'Foobar'; and
- who have addresses with a postal_code of '12345'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're looking for exact values, you can pass a hash of the values you'd like to match to `where`. Each referenced model is its own nested hash, as in the example below:

```
Person.
  where(:first_name => 'Bob').
  where(:last_name => 'Smith').
  where(:address => { :postal_code => '12345' }).   # queries associated Address
  where(:address => { :city => 'Foobar' })          # queries associated Address
```